# C++: 32 vs 64 bit stream operations

Tags: c++, stream, 64-bit

If I write an int into a fstream in a 32 application and the read that int back in a 64 bit application, should I expect the value to be different? If so (and I presume it is), what is the best way to achieve architecture-independent stream operations?

Comment: Are we to assume the `fstream` is *formatted* output/input and not in binary mode? Or the opposite?

Comment: At WhozCraig said, this really depends on whether you do formatted (=text) or unformatted (=binary) output.

Comment: I would like to recommend protobuf as a good serialization system that is language as well as platform agnostic. https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read and write using `operator<<` and `operator>>`, it will be platform independent, assuming that the integer is small enough to fit in both types, since if will be written as text. If you use `ostream::read` and `osteam::write`, it will not be platform independent, since you will be writing binary data.

If you don't need raw performance, using a text format is the easiest way to achieve platform independence. If you need better performance, you should look at a serialization library. Boost has a good cross-platform one.

Answer (score 2):

Well it depends if you write binary or in ASCII. If you write your numbers in ASCII (UTF-8) then the reading should produce the same result.

I would recommend that you use the `boost::serializaton` package to read and write data in a controlled and uniform manner.

However if it works in the opposite direction is not certain, i.e. from 64 bit to 32 bit.  It depends on your compiler, if it compiles `int`s to 64 bits then you might write values that can not be read into 32 bit `int`s. Even if you write to a formatted stream.

However there are no guarantees as the size of an `int` in C++, just that is larger or equal in size to a `short`. It is up to the compiler.

If you want to be really sure you can use GMP to handle large integers, then validate the data automatically.